# Input entry for form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to have my input controls render the same as the image below. But I am having some difficulty. I am trying to render multiple controls in this fashion. Where do I start? I have tried using a TableView, with An EntryCell, but it doesn't quite like the one in the image.

[image]

Any direction you can point me in would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Grid is the way to go. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/

Comment: Thanks guys. Really helped.